Smallest group that is generated by involutions and has a non-real-valued character
A finite group is called totally orthogonal if every representation has a strictly positive Frobenius-Schur indicator, equivalently the image of every representation is conjugate to a group of real matrices.
It is known that every totally orthogonal group is generated by involutions. But not every finite group generated by involutions is totally orthogonal. For example $ A_7 $ is generated by involutions but has two irreducible complex valued characters of degree 10 (taking values in the quadratic extension $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7}) $, specifically the ring of integers $ \mathbb{Z}[\frac{-1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}] $ with class number $1$).
What is the smallest group generated by involutions that is not totally orthogonal? Is it $ A_7 $? My guess is that it is actually $ \mathrm{PSL}(2,7) $, but I'm just not sure if $ \mathrm{PSL}(2,7) $ can be generated by involutions.

${\rm PSL}(2,7)$ is simple, so it is certainly generated by involutions. In fact all finite nonabelian simple groups are generated by three involutions.
